# How to intersect values from two data frames with R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, transpose, cbind

I would like to create a new column for a data frame with values from the intersection of a row and a column.

I have a data.frame called "time":

```
q   1    2   3   4    5
a   1    13  43  5    3
b   2    21  12  3353 34
c   3    21  312 123  343
d   4    123 213 123  35
e   4556 11  123 12   3
```

And another table, called "event":

```
q   dt
a   1
b   3
c   4
d   2
e   1
```

I want to put another column called inter on the second table that will be fill the values that are in the intersection between the q and the columns dt from the first data.frame. So the result would be this:

```
q   dt  inter
a   1   1
b   3   12
c   4   123
d   2   123
e   1   4556
```

I have tried to use `merge(event, time, by.x = "q", by.y = "dt")`, but it generate the error that they aren't the same id. I have also tried to transpose the time data.frame to cross section the values but I didn't have success.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)
merge(event, melt(time, id.vars = "q"), 
      by.x=c('q','dt'), by.y=c('q','variable'), all.x = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
  q dt value
1 a  1     1
2 b  3    12
3 c  4   123
4 d  2   123
5 e  1  4556
```

Notes

We use the function `melt` from the package `reshape2` to convert the data frame **time** from wide to long format. And then we merge (left outer join) the data frames  **event** and the melted **time** by two columns (q and dt in event, q and variable in the melted time) .

Data:

```
time <- structure(list(q = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e"), class = "factor"), `1` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4556L), `2` = c(13L, 
21L, 21L, 123L, 11L), `3` = c(43L, 12L, 312L, 213L, 123L), `4` = c(5L, 
3353L, 123L, 123L, 12L), `5` = c(3L, 34L, 343L, 35L, 3L)), .Names = c("q", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

event <- structure(list(q = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e"), class = "factor"), dt = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("q", 
"dt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little clunky but it works:

```
inter=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(time)) {
    xx=merge(time,event,by='q')
    dt=xx$dt
    z=y[i,dt[i]+1]
    inter=c(inter,z)
    final=cbind(time[,1],dt,inter)
}
colnames(final)=c('q','dt','inter')
```

Hope it helps.

Output:

```
     q dt inter
[1,] 1  1     1
[2,] 2  3    12
[3,] 3  4   123
[4,] 4  2   123
[5,] 5  1  4556
```